# ErrorException in SessionGuard.php | Getting error when trying to register user while creating new order

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want user to register and also buy a package. To do that I took input for registration details and package details. Now when I'm processing order to save package details in session and register, I get this error : `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\View\View given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\rename\app\Traits\OrderRegister.php on line 63 and defined`. I'm using an trait to register user and return back to function when registration is complete.

**OrderController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Package;
use App\ListingType;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Order;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Traits\OrderRegister;


class OrderController extends Controller
{
    use OrderRegister;


    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index($type)
    {
        $listingtype = ListingType::where('type', '=', $type)->first();
        if ($listingtype) {
            $packages = $listingtype->packages()->get();
            return view('packages.index', compact('packages'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create($id)
    {
        $package = Package::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return view('order.create_loggedin', compact('package'));
        }
        else {
            return view('order.create_register', compact('package'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process a new order request. Store order values in session.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function process(Request $request)
    {
        $order = ['package_id' => $request->package_id, 'order_qty' => $request->no_of_listing];
        session(['order' => $order]);
        if (Auth::guest()) {

            return $this->register($request); // need to check session for orders available in OrderRegister trait.
        }
        return $this->store($request);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {   

        if($request->session()->has('order')) {
            $package = Package::where('id', '=', $request->package_id )->first();
            if($request->user() == Auth::user()) {

                for( $n=1;$n<=$request->no_of_listing;$n++) {
                    $order = new Order;
                    $order->package_id = $request->package_id;
                    $order->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                    $order->expire_at = Carbon::now()->modify('+'.$package->duration_in_months.' months');
                    $order->save();
                }

                return redirect('/');
            }
        }

    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**trait : OrderRegister.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;

trait OrderRegister
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'username' => 'required|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        $user->profile()->save(new UserProfile);
        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

        Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($request->all()));

        return $this->store($request);
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during registration.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function getGuard()
    {
        return property_exists($this, 'guard') ? $this->guard : null;
    }
}
```

I could not find any solution for this error so created my own thread for the first time please someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It throws an error because you are trying to `login` a vue.

in your `OrderController.php` you are using `create` method which return a view.
this method will override the `create` method on your trait.

So you have something like this :

```
Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login(/* A view */);
```

you can at least rename the method on the trait from `create` to `createUser` for example.

then you call it from the guard like this :

```
Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->createUser($request->all()));
```

Comment: Thanks @zorx , that answer worked for me. I know there were some other errors too in my code but I corrected them and now its working perfectly fine.